# phpexcel not creating new sheet

Tags: phpexcel

I am trying to create new sheet in .xls file using PHPExcel library.
But it is not creating new sheet. Also not renaming if asked to rename existing sheet.
My code looks like this

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheetId = 1;
$objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, $sheetId);
$title="Simple";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($title);
echo date('H:i:s') , " Worksheet renamed";
?>
```

Can anybody please help 
I have referred [need to create xsl file with name and had different sheet name](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/244738)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code (and the `PHPExcel` code) to see where it goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php
/** PHPExcel */
include 'PHPExcel.php';

/** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';
echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Rename sheet
echo date('H:i:s') . " Rename sheet\n";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, "xyz");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('abc');

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));



// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
?>
```